# Is a CSS virus possible? (or any security breach)

Tags: css, security, virus

Is it possible to have a CSS virus, or what could be the closer of it? (=a non virus but something harmful for the security)

What kind of security breaches could it exploit?

Comment: Here's a similar question [from the Security StackExchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/123733).

Answer (score 3):

Not a virus, that would not be possible. The only thing that comes to mind is this:

> https://hackaday.com/2018/02/25/css-steals-your-web-data/

It abuses the fact that you can select an element based on an attribute's value.

Really clever!

Edit: There is a deprecated CSS property that was usable in IE5.5 (I think) that allowed you to define arbitrary js to be executed at run time. Someone demonstrated that you could put the entirety of jQuery in the property value and it ran. Obviously, this is not very useful today, but interesting, nonetheless. If I find this I will add it to this response.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is a browser side language there for the only way you would be able to execute harmful code in it would be to re-name the file to something like .exe or .php.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a virus via css. But this is an interesting article about fetching userdata with it https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/css-code-can-be-abused-to-collect-sensitive-user-data/

Answer (score 0):

The answers that you have gotten stating it is not possible, are correct, 
as long as everything works the way it is supposed to.

But since, at least with respect to security, everything on the internet is broken (and most other code as well) in one way or another, it is certainly possible for CSS to be a 
carrier of maleficent CSS that exploits security holes either in the CSS parser or the execution of CSS script content.

Then again, that is of course not specific to CSS, but also true for HTML/JS/images etc,
or basically any input from an unsecured source being parsed by any piece of software on your machine.

The access gained from these attack vectors can then be used to inject or
create a virus on the fly.